# To find line number where exception was thrown in java/grails

Tags: java, exception, grails

I have to write logic for detecting what line of code was exception thrown so we can go fix that issue later. The exception object's getStackTrace() gives us a list of stacktrace each with level. I am not interested in getting lowest place where exception was thrown but rather my class method which was responsible in passing parameters. 
Here is an example of what i am asking

```
class Test {
    void divide() {
    try{
        float i = 1/0
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        def v = e.getStackTrace()[0]
        println v.getClassName()
    }
    }
}
```

This would print class java.math.BigDecimal but i am interested in getting Test class so i can go to it's divide and fix this bug. Now, Test appears in some nth line which i cannot know in run time. One approach would be to iterate stacktrace list and try finding class which is custom developed but how to detect that? Or if there is some library function that already does that it would be great.

Comment: So, basically you're asking how to find element in a list, right?

Comment: Yeah. in context to example given, i want the stacktrace element which has className=Test and method=divide

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
println e.stackTrace.find {
  it.className == 'Test' && it.methodName == 'divide'
}
```

Or, I guess you want to check all levels of stacktrace, then:

```
Throwable t = e
StackTraceElement found = null
while (!found && t) {
  found = e.stackTrace.find {
    it.className == 'Test' && it.methodName == 'divide'
  }
  t = e.cause
}
println found
```

Comment: the example i gave you is dummy... i am talking about a generic method of detecting exception location in any code...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean

Comment: the solution that you provided is dependent on the example i provided. I want a solution that is not dependent on knowing the class name in first place like Test here. To better state my problem, I am having a global catch mechanism where i receive exceptions thrown in one place. Now that piece of code has to find which line did the exception occurred. One way is to dump entire stacktrace into database so developers can later go through the stacktrace themselves but i want to avoid those lengthy stacktraces.

Comment: You could pass variables instead of constants. Like `it.className == targetClassName` instead of hardcoded `'Test'`. Or filter by package like `it.className.startsWith('com.company.project')`